# How to arrange database menus in programatically way?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am having a problem in display menus from database to my web application. I store all the required menus in the database and fetch it on page load and display to users. I am able to fetch it from database but i cant seem to find a best possible way to display it. I am fetching it as stdClass object in laravel this is how it looks

```
    mastermenu     | abbreviation | submenutitle | submenuitems
-----------------------------------------------------------
Human Resource        hrm            H Title 1      H Item A
Human Resource        hrm            H Title 1      H Item B
Human Resource        hrm            H Title 1      H Item C
Human Resource        hrm            H Title 1      H Item D
Human Resource        hrm            H Title 2      Null
Procurement           pro            P Title 1      P Item A
Procurement           pro            P Title 1      P Item B
Procurement           pro            P Title 1      P Item C
Procurement           pro            P Title 2      Null
Procurement           pro            P Title 3      Null
Procurement           pro            P Title 4      Null
Accounts              acc            Null           Null        
Logistic              log            L Title 1      L Item A
Logistic              log            L Title 1      L Item B
```

and this is how i want to display it. I have done the Styling for the menu but pragmatically is the problem, if i can display in this way i can a sure myself i will be able to display with styling css. So how can I display the fetched result in this way

```
Human Resource 
        hrm
            H Title 1
                H Item A
                H Item B
                H Item C
                H Item D
            H Title 2
Procurement     
        Pro 
            P Title 1
                P Item A
                P Item B
                P Item C
            P Title 2
            P Title 3
            P Title 4
 Accounts
        acc
 Logistic
        log
            L Title 1
                L Item A
                L Item B
```

I would be grateful if you guys could lend me ideas on how to achieve the above mentions output. Note: I am using php and the stdClass object is being output using foreach loop as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm to old for this kind of stuff:
The keyword to search for is "[`control break`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break)"

You need to start a new "group" whenever a new value in one of your "sublevel" columns like 
`abbreviation` starts and close any previously opened group or subgroup.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Axel Amthor for your valuable input. will try implementing control break.